# Bug with CSS-Perspective on Element and Smooth Scrolling with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling, webkit-perspective

I'm having a strange problem.

- I want to build a website which has a perspective set to 1500px.
- It's a one-page website, so I added a smooth scrolling script.

But the problem is, that it doesn't work correctly...
If i put off the perspective, everything works fine? What could I do to get it to work?

Here's my code...

```
.page-container{
    position: relative;
    perspective: 1500px;
    background: $bg-color--first;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

And the smooth scrolling

```
function smoothScroll (duration) {
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
      var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
      if( target.length ) {
        removeHamburger();
        console.log(target.offset().top);
          event.preventDefault();
          $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
          }, duration);
      }
  });
}
```

My  content is inside the page container, which is a sibling of my off-canvas navigation.

**EDIT:**

It doesn't scroll to the right position... It scrolls, but not to the section with the ID...

Comment: Explain what doesn't work.

Comment: I can reproduce that, through the perspective/parallax effect the target div changed it's position unexpectedly for JS... I don't have a solution though.

Comment: The Solution is to first save all offsets in a Variable and then scroll to the elements. I don't know why But it seems to work.